# Feature request for changing the badge shape

Tags: feature-request

Our current badges looks like a simple dot. Why don't we change the badge shape from dot to something like in the below image or any other symbols?

[image]

[Image Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Badge_1012.jpg)

Comment: I think that passes a wrong message. Our badges are more like boyscout medals than law enforcement symbols.

Comment: [math.SE] uses the three simple shapes for gold, silver and bronze badges, to surround their topic. I don't see a pressing need for our badges to be changed to the graphics of law-enforcing honor badges.

Comment: Changing good things is bad!

Comment: seems like you people love the dot. Yes, dot is everything. In regex, a dot would match any character :-)

Comment: A dot represents a zero as well. For `lim x -> infinity`, `0 = x + (-x)`. Because for `a = b + C` where `C` is a constant, `a > b` remains true. So zero is larger than infinity!

Comment: @AvinashRaj What is wrong with the simple dot? You have suggested a change, but without stating any good reason why it should be changed. Given it'll require a lot of dev time to make it fit in all areas of the site, and mobile etc, you need to argue a good case. And not just "Cos da fuzz badge is cool".

Comment: @James yep, my question fails to describe why? I already flagged this question for deletion..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why delete it? You asked a question, people have spent time reading it, thinking, commenting, answering, voting, etc. You should avoid deleting questions just because they didn't turn out the way you wanted. Either edit your question and make a case as to why your idea would be good (which you should have done in the first place really, we don't know your reasoning behind you proposing this), or just accept that (so far) no-one wants this :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*"Why don't we change the badge shape from the dot?"*

Why should we?

Everything on SO consists of simple shapes:  The logo, the "notification" icons, tags...

I don't see the added value of adding detail to those dots. As they are right now, they fit behind the rep just fine. If you were to add detail, you'd have to make them larger than those dots.

Unless you can think of a good "medal / badge" icon that's 6*6px (Heck, make it 8*8px), that doesn't require me to zoom in to see what it's supposed to be.

Comment: I suggest having jQuery for gold badges, "1" for silver badges, and "0" for bronze badges. That's totally programmer-adorable.

Comment: @Unihedron I suggest using the words `foo`, `bar` and `ni` for gold, silver and bronze badges. Even more adorable :)

Comment: I'd use an brown square for gold badges, a yellow one for silver badges, and a gray one for bronze badges.

Comment: @Cerbrus But... They're all squares, where's the twist? It's unfair! [math.SE] has three shapes (for badges), [so] only gets one!

Comment: The twist is that the gold badge gets the brown square, the silver one gets the yellow square, etc.

Comment: We should definitely keep the dot, but "*they fit behind the rep just fine*" does have [exceptions...](http://i.imgur.com/jI77avk.png)  ;)

Answer (score 9):

Here you go

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Just use this [userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) and create some nice PNGs:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        (SO) Custom badges
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle("\
span.badge1 { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9W65.png); width: 12px; }\
span.badge2 { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKLZu.png); width: 12px; }\
span.badge3 { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zG5X.png); width: 12px; }\
.topbar span.badge1 { width: 9px; }\
.topbar span.badge2 { width: 9px; }\
.topbar span.badge3 { width: 9px; }\
");
```

Or you can even copy the style from another SE site.

Comment: Those are some cute teddy bears ^_^

Comment: oh, dear, that's spot on, lol2much :)

Comment: [Here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/41913-so-custom-badges) is a link to a Greasy Monkey userscript to install, but you'll need Tampermonkey or something first.